# fullpage.js: normal scroll for particular sections?

Tags: fullpage.js

I am building a complex page with multiple sections based on the latest fullpage.js release (developer license). I have 3 full-height sections with auto scroll and then 3 more sub-sections. In the code it basically looks like this:

```
<div id="fullpage">
   <div class="section">content</div>
   <div class="section">content</div>
   <div class="section">content</div>
   ...
   <div class="section sub-section">content</div>
   <div class="section sub-section">content</div>
   <div class="section sub-section">content</div>
</div>
```

I want these sub-sections to have a normal scroll, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not something fullPage.js provides yet. 
The most you can do is include all those last sections inside the last section of your site and then use `scrollOverflow:true` to emulate the normal scroll behaviour as in [this example](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html).

See this [demo online](https://jsfiddle.net/alvarotrigo/54kcg8n2/2/)

```
<div id="fullpage">
   <div class="section">content</div>
   <div class="section">content</div>
   <div class="section">content</div>
   <div class="section">
       <div class="sub-section">sub content</div>
       <div class="sub-section">sub content</div>
       <div class="sub-section">sub content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using something like this:

```
sub-section{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
.sub-section{
  background: red;
}
.sub-section:nth-child(1){
  background: red;
}
.sub-section:nth-child(2){
  background: blue;
}
```