# Swiper - Slides status not updating correctly with mousewheel/freeMode/slidesperview:auto

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

Everything works fine if the slider is the only element in the page, but add an extra one after the swiper element and the active slide is always the first one. Adding `height: 100%` to `.swiper-container` makes it work fine, but then when you go to the end of the page and back to top, footer is fixed. Anyone has a workaround?

Example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/swiper-demo-15-free-mode-no-fixed-positions-losg12?file=style.css

Answer (score 0):

Your issue only looks like a bug (But it's not).
The footer is not fixed but when you hover `A area` you scroll the **swiper** `mousewheel: true` (not the page).

[image]

### One Solution/Idea:

`[1]`Disable/Enable scroll `[2]` if footer is **visible**.

- **Part 1:** Use mousewheel API methods:

```
mySwiper.mousewheel.disable();  
mySwiper.mousewheel.enable();
```

- **Part 2:** Use [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) (If the footer is visible disable mousewheel).Read more: [How to Know when an Element Gets Visible in the Screen During Scrolling](https://usefulangle.com/post/113/javascript-detecting-element-visible-during-scroll#:%7E:text=To%20know%20whether%20the%20element%20is%20fully%20visible%20in%20viewport,height%20and%20bottom%20%3E%3D%200.)

```
var observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
  // isIntersecting is true when element and viewport are overlapping
  // isIntersecting is false when element and viewport don't overlap
  if(entries[0].isIntersecting === true){
    console.log('Element has just become visible in screen');
    swiper.mousewheel.disable();    
  }
  else{
    swiper.mousewheel.enable(); 
  }
}, { threshold: [0] });

observer.observe(document.querySelector("#footer"));
```

#### Snippet

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  freeMode: true,
  mousewheel: {
    invert: false,
  },
  // If we need pagination
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  scrollbar: {
    el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
    draggable: true,
  }
});

var observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
  // isIntersecting is true when element and viewport are overlapping
  // isIntersecting is false when element and viewport don't overlap
  if(entries[0].isIntersecting === true){
    console.log('Element has just become visible in screen');
    swiper.mousewheel.disable();    
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "mousewheel.disable!";
  }
  else{
    swiper.mousewheel.enable(); 
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "mousewheel.enable!";
  }
}, { threshold: [0.1] });

/* threshold is a number between 0 and 1, that represents the viewable area of the target element in the screen. For example, 0 represents no area of element is visible. A value of 0.10 represents about 10% area is viewable in screen. Value of 1 means element is fully viewable in screen.*/

observer.observe(document.querySelector("#footer"));
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;

  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

nav{
  min-height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: lightgray;
}

footer{
  min-height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: brown;
  color: white;
}

#message{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  padding: 10px;
  background: brown;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid gray;
}

#status{
  background: yellow;
  color: red;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<span id="message">Status: <b id="status">True</b></span>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css">

<nav>Navbar</nav>
<!-- Slider main container -->
<main class="swiper-container">
    <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    </div>
    <!-- If we need pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

    <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

    <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
    <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
</main>

<footer id="footer">Footer</footer>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/ezra_siton/pen/JjRbrJM

### Fullpage.js

One more idea is to use a full-page scroll plugin (More control):

- https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/
- https://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling/

Related: [fullpage.js: normal scroll for particular sections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54997782/fullpage-js-normal-scroll-for-particular-sections)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and research time, I ended up disabling swiper and only using IntersectionObserver, too bad you cannot not specify any fixed height in this case :/

Comment: This answer solve somehow your Issue? (Y/N)

Comment: Not really, I was looking for a built-in autoHeight feature. Other solutions work but are workarounds.

Comment: Maybe use fullpage.js (Swiper is not really for "One page scroll" effect).

Comment: I will look into that, thank you! (for now I've just used a manual IntersectionObserver method)